# What is really "wp_nonce_field" and how does it work?

Tags: nonce

```
wp_nonce_field()
```

This function making me so confused. The documentation in wordpress codex doesn't make sense. I can't understand why and how to use it.

Last two week I am wasting/spending my time to understand some of the wordpress function to develop a video plugin. Please anyone explain this a function simply.

Answer (score -3):

`wp_nonce_field()` means the nonce field is used to validate that the contents of the form came from the location on the current site and not somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks! Please simply explain the parameters of the function.

Comment: It does not get the hidden filed values!

Comment: `wp_nonce_field('action_name','nonce_field_name')`